# How to store multiple values on a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL and I try to understand some basic stuff.

I have 2 tables:

- users:  **ID | NAME | EMAIL | APPS**
- apps: **ID | NAME**

#### QUESTIONS

How do I create a third table based on those two, that as a JSON will look like this:

```
[
   { id: 1, name: 'Daniel', email: 'dan@iel.com', apps: [1,2,3]},
   { id: 2, name: 'Ben', email: 'dan@iel.com', apps: [1,5]},
   { id: 3, name: 'Maya', email: 'dan@iel.com', apps: [4]}
]
```

Query wise, how do I write a query that create a user like this, where apps is a list of ID's:

```
{ id: 1, name: 'Daniel', email: 'dan@iel.com, apps: [1,2,3]}
```

Comment: but why do you want to store it like JSON? it's not a right way according to normalization

Comment: I want to return a json that looks like this to the client. Im just not sure what is the SQL way of inserting and selecting this kind of data

Comment: you need to rebuild your result set to accomplish desired json format

Comment: just save values in their respective table and columns and when you'll read the data from the table then it will automatically give you object if single data or array of objects if multiple data

Answer (score 1):

would it not be better to use a pivot table.

pivot table:

```
[
  { pivot_id: user_id, app_id },
  { pivot_id: user_id, app_id },
]
```

a simple loop could be used to insert into pivot table

```
foreach(apps as app_id)
{
 query = "INSERT INTO pivot_table set user_id = `user_id`, app_id = `app_id` ";
}
```

Comment: Note that there's (probably) no need for a surrogate Primary Key here. (user_id,app_id) seems like a satisfactory PK